# Fail fast approach for file uploads exceeding file size limit via Jersey

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to find a way for a fail fast approach while uploading file via Jersey, if it exceeds file size limit. Currently, I have to wait till the entire file/stream is read and once I have the control in my Jersey endpoint handler, I have to calculate the size of the stream and then prevent further processing.

However examples using springmvc, make use of multipart Config for fail fast.
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-upload-example-using-multipartconfigelement/

I cannot use these annotations / servlet config with Jersey.
Is there a way to achieve something like this with Jersey?

Comment: see this open issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2986

Comment: which container do you use? maybe you could configure it for the container (e.g. possible for tomcat like described here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html#fileSizeThreshold%28%29

Comment: The documentation which you have shared talks about configuring for WebServlets. I have tried the same for Jersey and those annotations dont work on them.

Comment: Found any solution to this?